# How do I search a large text file (book)?

Tags: swift

I have tried to find the information in books and many places on the net all to no end.  What I want to do is an app which is basically a book.  I want to add a search function to it which is in an ideal world the ibooks search.  The other thing I am not clear on is where do I put the file (book) which is to be searched.  I hope this makes things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into the swift programming language to do it. You need to create your own index from the book text in order to search it efficiently. 
To create the index you first remove the stopwords -- words are very frequent and is not supposed to have search result like "the", "is", etc. (you can find a sample list of stopwords [here](http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords)). 
Next step would be stemming. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming). It is essentially converting words to their stem in order to find them when different derivation of them are searched. For example when one searches for run, you show results for ran too. 
After that you create an index which could be a simple dictionary of . 
To create the index you traverse the processed text (the stemmed text with no stopwords), and add every word to your index. If the word is already present in the index, you simply add the new occurrence to the index and if it is not there, you add it to the dictionary.

The above process does not need to be done necessarily using swift and you might be able to find programs that do this for you and you simply add the resulting index to your ios program.

Comment: many thanks for the info you are the first person who has even tried to answer the question everyone else has walked away.  I am new to this and have zero knowledge of programming so I am not only trying to teach myself Swift but I have an app 2/3 done..ty again for your help